# Multiple Recursion Calls

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int y(int i){
    cout<<i<<endl;
    i++;

    if(i==10){
        return 10000000;
    }
    int left=y(i);
    int right=y(i)+1;
    return right;

}
int main()
{
    cout<<y(1);

    return 0;
}
```

In this code after left(9) has executed shouldn't "i" come out of the stack and execute right(1) ?But while debugging I have noticed that right(9) gets executed.Could someone please explain this to me.Thank you in advance.

Comment: The line after `int left=y(i);` is `int right=y(i)+1;`, so when `int left=y(9);` returns, the next thing to happen is `int right=y(9)+1;`. (Recursive functions work exactly like non-recursive functions.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Execution doesn't come out of the stack. Each `return` removes one call.

so when `i==9` the call in `int left=y(9)` will be followed by the call in `int right=y(9)+1` because `i==9` still.

Only then will the call to `y(8)` return and so on through `y(7)`,`y(6)` and so on down to the original call in `main()` of `y(1)`.

Like any stack structure it is unloaded in the reverse order it's built.

Personally I think of those clever plate dispensers where the weight of the plates is balanced by a spring.

When you call a function you create a new local environment (put a new plate on the stack) and a function returns the top plate is discarded.

When you discard the bottom plate you're returning from `main()` and the program finishes.

Imagine y(9) printed on the top plate and y(8) on the one underneath.
At the end is a instrumented version of the code showing the stack size and number of calls made.

[image: Spring balanced plate stacker frame]

```
#include <iostream>

int y(int i,char from,int &calls,int &stack){
    ++calls;
    ++stack;
    std::cout<<"entering y("<< i<<','<<from<<") "<<calls<<' '<<stack<<'\n';
    i++;

    if(i==10){
        std::cout<<"returning "<<10000000<<" from y(" << i<<','<<from<<") [1]\n";
        --stack;
        return 10000000;
    }
    int left=y(i,'l',calls,stack);
    int right=y(i,'r',calls,stack)+1;
    std::cout<<"returning "<<right<<" from y(" << i<<','<<from<<") [2]\n";
    --stack;
    return right;

}

int main()
{
  int calls{0};
  int stack{1};//We're in main().
  std::cout<<y(1,'m',calls,stack);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: for a minute there I thought I landed at the wrong site :) nice pic :)

Comment: @OrenIshShalom The mechanism is usually hidden inside a cabinet. It sort of emphasises that the only way to interact with an abstract stack is push, pop, and (usually) is-empty. Everything else is hidden.